# Do singularities in the solution of the wave equation propagate with the wave speed?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

I'm interested in the speed of propagation of singularities of a solution to the following wave equation.
\begin{equation}
(\partial_{tt}+A)u = 0
\end{equation}
where A is a second order elliptic operator. One could imagine either the purely highest order case $A=-c^2(x)\Delta$, or $A$ having the divergence form $A=-\nabla\cdot c^2\nabla$, or a mixed case. It seems to be common sense, that these singularities propagate with speed 1 (in the Riemannian metric induced by the principal symbol of $A$) along the characteristics of the PDE. Why is that?

**So far I found out:**
From the theory for Hyperbolic PDE it is known that singularities occurring in the solution (for instance, in the initial condition) are propagated along the so-called characteristics of the PDE.
The second common statement is the one of *finite speed of propagation*, which asserts that the solution $u$ at a fixed point $(t_0,x_0)$ only depends on the former values of $u$ given in the cone $C=\{(t,x), \operatorname{dist}(x,x_0)<t_0-t\}$, where $\operatorname{dist}(x,y)$ is the distance of $x$ to $y$ in the Riemannian metric induced by the second order coefficients of $A$.

Another important tool to describe the propagation of singularities is the concept of a *wave front set*. Roughly speaking, the wave front set $WF(u)$ of a distribution $u$ contains all points $(x,\xi)\in \mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n$, where $x$ is in the singular support of $u$ and $\xi$ gives the direction in which the product of $u$ and any $\phi\in C_0^\infty$ is not rapidly decreasing.
Now for a wide class of operators (including hyperbolic operators), one can show that as soon as there is a point $(x_0,\xi_0)\notin WF(u)$, all points on any characteristic strip going through $(x_0,\xi_0)$ have to be regular as well. That is, the singularities propagate along the characteristics in the direction indicated by the wave front set, and they do not disappear.

**The question is now:** How can I glue this together with the finite speed of propagation to get a generalized version of Huygens principle for the singular support (rather than for the support of $u$ in the simple $(2n+1)D$ constant coefficient case)? In the case of constant coefficients, the boundary $\partial C$ of the cone $C$ seems to be exactly the characteristic surface going through $x_0$, and the singularities propagate along straight lines on the cone; that is, they propagate with the (constant) wave speed $c$. In the general case, I think that the characteristics cannot cross $\partial C$, as this would violate the computed propagation speed. But until now, I didn't see a proof that they actually lie on the boundary. That is, I wasn't able to exclude the case of a characteristic strip lying in the interior of $C$. As I mentioned, it seems to be common sense that such principles exist, but I didn't find an answer why this is correct.

[1]: Lars Hörmander. The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I-IV.

[2]: Lawrence C. Evans. Partial Differential Equations.